# Function of tassel in Chinese straight sword?

Tags: kung-fu, wushu, jian

Back when I started learning Chinese straight sword, tassels were almost universally utilized, but my sense is that in recent years, there has been movement away from using it, partly in service of conveying a more serious martial approach that dispenses with that which is not seen as essential.  But plenty of practitioner still use tassel.  Is this simply tradition, or are there valid reasons to employ it.

- What is the function of tassel in Chinese jian?

Comment: Google Fu:
https://internalwudangmartialarts.com/2016/05/27/why-chinese-swords-jian-always-have-tassels/
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-usage-of-the-red-tassel-usually-seen-hanging-from-Chinese-jian-swords

Comment: @SteveWeigand Good link, but, like most sources on the arts, not entirely reliable. [Major Methods of Wudang Sword](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Major_Methods_of_Wudang_Sword.html?id=uP1ZnSTsVCEC), for instance, features no tassels, nor any mentions of tassel, if I recall correctly.  Weichardt is correct overall about usages, with various omissions, but no explication, and no cautions against certain "crowd pleasing" tricks one might see. Also omits long tassel, which is not surprising, in that it's much more rarely taught & practiced.

Answer (score 4):

*This answer relates to a tassel of sufficient length to wrap the wielder's wrist.  I typically use one with a string length 9 inches, but prefer 12", which are harder to find, but, perhaps counter-intuitively, allow better control.  Tassels with no string attached directly to the pommel have no function beyond aesthetics.*

- Distract an opponent

This is typically the generic given answer, the idea that the moving tassel can draw the eye and distract a competitor.  However, as serious practitioners must train their gaze to be cognizant of all details of the opponent and surroundings, and is mostly concerned with the opponent's blade, stance, and orientation, this distraction function is only likely to be a factor against a novice.

- Flick the eyes

This is another common explanation, and has some utility.  There are certain counters that allow for the tassel to directed at an opponent's eyes, which, if it makes contact, will result in some stinging and tearing up. "Sparrow carries the soil" from Tai Chi sword is another technique can be executed such that the tassel leads into the face of an opponent.  As these techniques can only be utilized at extremely close range, it can be advantageous if executed successfully since the opponent is well within range of a finishing cut.

- Provide counter-balance for certain strikes

For some techniques, putting energy into the tassel can provide a counterbalance for a cut, "spreading wings" as an example, which perhaps provides some small advantage.  This is because, although the tassel is typically light, sufficient inertia can be generated to balance against a light, flexible blade.

- Defense against blades

Loose fabric is well known for its ability to snag the point of blades. Tassels can be used in a similar manner, as even edges don't do well against loose fabric.  Where a tassel is controlled properly such that the string is rarely entirely taut, it can redirect an opponent's blade out of the intended attack vector. (If entirely taut, the tassel string can be cut.)

- Wrapping a pole-based weapon to set up a cut

This is something I was not taught, but validated in research.  The tassel can wrap a weapon like a spear, and the fencer, having superior leverage, can simultaneously redirect the pole weapon while making a decisive cut. (In this case, the tassel must be attached around bottom of the handle, above the pommel, not the weak fastener at the end of modern screw-based [tangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_(tools)), or it will be ripped off.)

- Wrapping one's own wrist intentionally to provide stronger grip.

This is something you see rarely, likely because it also has the effect of reducing wrist mobility, and wrist flexibility is arguably the primary requirement of Chinese straight sword.

**DEEPER PURPOSE**

- **Using a tassel makes the practice significantly more difficult**

This is because the practitioner can no longer focus only on movement of and energy to the blade, but must also precisely control the movement of the pommel, avoiding allowing too much energy into the tassel.  Failure to properly control the tassel can result in wrapping the wrist (although even high-level masters can have this happen on occasion. In this instance, the practitioner takes it as an opportunity to naturally unwrap the tassel in subsequent movements, without compromising martial technique.)

- **Demonstrates level of control**

In the same way looking at a practitioner's off-hand in weapons forms is a simple way to gauge their skill, observing a the tassel reveals the level of control. Nearly all of the energy should be in the blade—if the tassel has too much movement, it indicates energy bleed to the wrong place.

Even in energetic cuts, one avoids the tassel spinning like a propeller, and seeks to direct that energy in a line, such that the tassel bounces once rather than spins.  At a very high level, a master can execute a cut with great focus [(*fa jin* 發勁)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa_jin) where the tassel only expresses a minimal bounce, with no linear extension of the string at all.

- **Gauge one's own level of calm in internal styles**

It's not uncommon for the mind not to be clear during practice, which can result in insufficient calm for Tai Chi and Wudang sword.  Seeing one's tassel bouncing around in a poorly controlled manner is a clear signal to the practitioner.

(Note that calm doesn't necessarily mean slow movement at a steady pace throughout—although internal sword is often practiced this way. Real fencing involves tempo, such that an advanced Wudang practitioner will vary pacing in both practice and exhibition—some movements slow, some quick and lively.)

---

Long tassel sword is a special case.  In contemporary Wushu, this refers to a string+tassel fringe longer than the blade, but the traditional form I was taught utilizes a string that is itself significantly longer than the blade, typically more than twice as long, and this informs my understanding of tassel in general.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple answer — Easy to validate

There is a technique [絞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B5%9E) that is sometimes referred to as "swirling" the sword, though the common usage is to "wind" in the sense of "wrap" or "intertwine".  [Literally "silk + crossing"; the technique is a form of silk reeling, where the waist is used to put continual momentum into the blade via a chosen axis, where small circles are most desirable.]

It's an on-guard position where you trace the point of the straight sword in small circles.  I was taught had at waist level, palm up blade pointing into the opponent's eyes, which results in protecting the torso, the primary defensive requirement.

Typically, one walks the circle while practicing this technique.

- The tassel of a practitioner with sufficient technique will have minimal bounce, and always remain in a generally downward position below the pommel a the end of the string, because the momentum into the tassel is directed downward.

The utility of this technique is it is an on-guard position with constant momentum, circular, out of which the counter (parry) to any given attack, cut or thrust, can be developed.

The utility of practicing this technique with the tassel is that it forces the practitioner to think of the axis as fulcrum, controlling and thinking about the tip and pommel simultaneously, even when executing techniques with the end of the blade.

Use of tassel reinforces the high level of control needed in swordplay, reinforces what is sometimes referred to as the "action" of the sword via the axis/fulcrum, and alerts the practitioner that energy is not being directed in the proper vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good video on Youtube about the origin of the tassel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl4PtViHEpM

The short of it: they originate primarily from theatrical conventions of Chinese martial arts practice.  However, what they may be representative of are historical jian lanyards which often are adjustable with a bead or loop and have tassel-like ends from the frayed cord.  Historical jian on occasion do have holes in the grip for lanyards to secure the sword to the wrist like [this very famous example from the Metropolitan Museum of Art](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/27931):
[image]
And there are some examples of historical presentation jian with tassels like [this one](http://www.swordsantiqueweapons.com/s1246_full.html):
[image]
It wouldn't be that far of a stretch for the functional lanyard to evolve into the ornamental tassel over time for the modern performance aspect of Wushu and other Chinese martial arts.  So originally the function of them was to secure the sword to the wrist, but now it's mainly ornamentation.  Also a bit of niche benefit to them is that they add an extra weight to the end of the sword that can sort of counterbalance the entire weapon when it's swinging around loosely, but that's honestly a minor benefit if any. :P